# Display a fixed-length subset of a list in a Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to display a fixed-length subset of a set of related objects in a Django template. For example, imagine that I have a Car, which has related object Owner. I would like to display the three most recent owners, but also always display three entries even if there are fewer. So

```
Ford Fiesta AA11 1AA
    1. John Smith
    2. Jane Smith
    3. Jenny Smith

Aston Martin DB9
    1. Richard Rich
    2.
    3.
```

even if the Fiesta has had 10 owners (and the DB9 has had only one).

The naive way to do this would be

```
<h1>{{car.name}}</h1>
<ol>
  {% for owner in car.owner_set|slice:":3" %}
  <li>{{owner.name}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

but this will only display one list item if there has only been one owner.

I could also add lines like

```
{% if car.owner_set|length < 2 %}<li></li>{% endif %}
{% if car.owner_set|length < 3 %}<li></li>{% endif %}
```

but that's terrible. Is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way seems to me to be to define a new filter.

Create a `templatetags` package in the relevant app and add a file called `liststuff.py` (or whatever name you wish) with the following code:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def exactlength(listlike_thing, desired_length):
    list_thing = list(listlike_thing)
    if len(list_thing) < desired_length:
        # pad the list with as many empty strings as needed
        list_thing += ([''] * (desired_length - len(list_thing)))
    return list_thing[:desired_length]
```

Then, at the top of your template, load that file (if you called your file something else, change this line accordingly):

```
{% load liststuff %}
```

and in your loop initialisation, pass your values through the filter:

```
{% for owner in car.owner_set|exactlength:3 %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom filter or similar, but for just the one instance, I would add a method to the Car model that returned what you're after, something like:

```py
def three_latest_owners(self):
    num = 3
    latest = list(self.owner_set.all()[:num])
    latest += [None] * num
    return latest[:num]
```

Then in the template, `{% for owner in car.three_latest_owners %}`

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, not the most elegant solution nor the most re-usable, but the real naive solution would surely be:

```
<h1>{{car.name}}</h1>
<ol>
  <li>{{car.owner_set.0.name}}</li>
  <li>{{car.owner_set.1.name}}</li>
  <li>{{car.owner_set.2.name}}</li>
</ol>
```